# how do i differentiate SortedMap from TreeMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I found out different spark job performances would result from trying SortedMap and TreeMap respectively. SortedMap containing big data in Dataset caused worse performance than TreeMap did.

But I traced the source code and found sortedmap is just converted to treemap when using SortedMap.empty[A, B] to create it.

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[A, B](implicit ord: Ordering[A]): CanBuildFrom[Coll, (A, B), SortedMap[A, B]] = new SortedMapCanBuildFrom[A, B]
def empty[A, B](implicit ord: Ordering[A]): ***SortedMap[A, B] = TreeMap.empty[A, B]***
```

Could anyone give some hints on this issue? what are the real differences between `SortedMap.empty[A, B]` and `TreeMap.empty[A, B]`?

Comment: How were you "trying SortedMap and TreeMap"? How did you measure performance? What was the difference?

Comment: I extracted data from a hbase table and manipulated them with SortedMap in a spark Dataset. the spark job's execution time was remarkably longer than that with substituting SortedMap with TreeMap. Nothing but this discrepancy in the code. what i am wondering is why. why did such phenomenon emerge?

Comment: show the code, and explain how you measure execution time, and what difference you observe in how many experiments.